# Python API with Response - Authentication

Tags: python, json, api, authentication, python-requests

Working with the [Streak CRM API](https://www.streak.com/api/) by using Python and Request. I am getting 4XX errors depending on how I phrase the request. (Examples below)

```
response = requests.get('https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines?api-key=xxxxxxxx')
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
```

Result: 401 "Authentication Required for Streak API: try HTTP Basic Auth or cookie auth"

If I add ".json" after the file path:

```
requests.get('https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines.json?api-key=xxxxxxxx')
```

Result: 400 "Invalid API path specified" So I am assuming that I was authenticated but just have a poorly defined file path.

But if I use the same file path and credentials entered in the terminal:

```
curl https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipeline -u xxxxxxxx:
```

Works like a charm.

Why would the file path work in the terminal but not in python? Why do I need to add .json to my file path? New to using APIs so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but rephrasing it like below worked. I received status code 200:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines', auth=('xxxxxx',''))
```

The API key goes in the username parameter, and the password parameter is left blank.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you all you need to know. For [Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) you put the authorization info in the request headers, not in the url. When you add `.json` to a endpoint, that usually means that you want a JSON response. The reason why it worked with curl is because curl's -u flag is setting the Auth header.